# eksctl "no clusters found"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks, eksctl

I am currently trying out aws eks and I am havin a problem managing my cluster via eksctl. Now creating a cluster via eksctl works just fine using

```sh
eksctl create cluster --region [region] --name my-cluster
```

The cluster comes up correctly and it also shows in the AWS console Web GUI but if I try to get it with

```sh
eksctl get clusters
```

I get

> No clusters found

I set up my roles as described in the documentation (EKS Cluster) role and added Access Key Id and Secret Access Key to my configuration. But could this be an issue with the permissions? If not, what else could it be

Comment: What does `kubectl config get-contexts` give you?

Comment: current namepsace is correct. i also can deploy correctly. it's just the eksctl that has its problems. I can also delete the cluster in the console again but would rather do it via eksctl

Comment: Including the region of your cluster will make it work.
use --region with the above eksctl command

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Have you tried to run:

```
eksctl get clusters --region [region]
```

What's your default region configured, probably you have it set up to a different one than the one where you created the cluster, e.g.:

```
$ eksctl get clusters
No clusters found

$ eksctl get clusters --region eu-west-2
NAME                REGION
eksworkshop-eksctl  eu-west-2

$ export AWS_REGION=eu-west-2
$ eksctl get clusters
NAME                REGION
eksworkshop-eksctl  eu-west-2
```

Comment: Thanks. You saved me a few hours here as someone who is new to aws

Answer (score 4):

In my case, we had a different profile to the `default`, under **.aws/config**, so I had to pass `--profile PROFILE` parameter.